# I need help upgrading OroCommerce to 4.1.1

Tags: orocommerce

I just upgraded from 3.1.17 to 4.1.1 and I'm finding a problem with my shopping lists.

When I get to /customer/shoppinglist/5064 I see this:

[image]

Looking at my log files from production I see:

```
[2020-06-23 17:42:56] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\UndefinedMethodError: "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDigitalAsset" of class "Proxies\__CG__\Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Entity\File"." at /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/DigitalAssetBundle/Provider/FileTitleProvider.php line 47 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Attempted to call an undefined method named \"getDigitalAsset\" of class \"Proxies\\__CG__\\Oro\\Bundle\\AttachmentBundle\\Entity\\File\". at /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/DigitalAssetBundle/Provider/FileTitleProvider.php:47)"} []
```

I went to look at the code and I see that in fact there is no method `getDigitalAsset` in oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/DigitalAssetBundle/Provider/FileTitleProvider.php, nor in the proxy... how can this be?

I checked this on my VM (where the problem is not happening) and I see that there's this definition in the proxy class:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getDigitalAsset()
{

    $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'getDigitalAsset', []);

    return parent::getDigitalAsset();
}
```

But again, I don't see a method called getDigitalAsset in the parent class.

I had some issues when doing the upgrade (I realized my nodejs wasn't upgraded as I thought it was), could that have anything to do with the issue?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I went through my platform upgrade again and found that there were some problems that prevented it from finishing completely.

This is what I found:

```
  > loading Oro\Bundle\CMSBundle\Migrations\Data\ORM\LoadImageSlider

In LoadImageSlider.php line 117:
                                                                               
  Attempted to call an undefined method named "setMainImage" of class "Oro\Bundle\CMSBundle\Entity\ImageSlide".
```

I commented out the loop inside the load method and re-run the upgrade. Then I got:

```
    > loading Oro\Bundle\CMSBundle\Migrations\Data\ORM\LoadImageSlider

In QueryException.php line 65:
                                                                               
  [Semantical Error] line 0, col 117 near 'digitalAsset': Error: Class Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Entity\File has no association named digitalAsset      
                                                                               

In QueryException.php line 43:
                                                                               
  SELECT file, digitalAsset, sourceFile FROM Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Entity\File file INNER JOIN file.digitalAsset digitalAsset INNER JOIN digitalAsset.sourceFile sourceFile WHERE file.parentEntityClass = :parentEntityClass  
   AND file.parentEntityId = :parentEntityId AND file.parentEntityFieldName =  
   :parentEntityFieldName
```

Finally I was able to complete the upgrade by commenting out the whole body of the load method

Answer (score 0):

> I had some issues when doing the upgrade (I realized my nodejs wasn't upgraded as I thought it was), could that have anything to do with the issue?

It looks like you have multiple versions of nodejs installed. To make an application use the right one, you can provide the absolute path to the executable  with [the AssetBundle configuration](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/bundles/platform/AssetBundle/#configuration-reference), like:

```yaml
# config/config.yml
oro_asset:
   nodejs_path: /usr/local/node
   npm_path: /usr/local/npm
```

Comment: That might have been an issue... how do you figure there are multiple nodejs versions installed?

Comment: Try `whereis node` and `whereis nodejs`. Also, you can check common locations, like `/usr/bin/node --version`,  `/usr/local/bin/node --version`. And check where is nodejs installed on your OS.

Comment: Got it. I checked and apparently I have only v12.18.1 installed, but again, I seem to remember there being an issue with node when I posted this, so you're probably right... I was just curious what tipped you about the possible duplication of nodejs. Thanks!