# I'm having trouble with extended entities

Tags: orocommerce

This question is related to [I need help upgrading OroCommerce to 4.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543582/i-need-help-upgrading-orocommerce-to-4-1-1).

I'm getting several errors related to extended entities... I believe there must be something wrong with cache building but I can't find the root cause (nor a solution :( ).

I checked the db structure in my production server against the VM where everything is working just fine and I can't see any significant difference (meaning the new fields such as `digitalAsset_id` for `oro_attachment_file` table or `wysiwyg` for `oro_fallback_localization_val` are there).

I just run an extra `php bin/console oro:migration:load --force -e prod` it didn't make a difference...

**Edit:**

Just checked the differences in the `var/cache` directory of both installations and in fact I see that the VM version has the methods that are missing from the prod one.

I uploaded the working code into the production server and re run the platform upgrade but I'm still running into issues.

Comment: I realized now that everytime I clear the cache I end up with non extended entity proxies.. any idea why this might be happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `oro:migration:load` command (or `oro:platform:update` that actually triggers migration load) failed for the first time, you have to:

- fix errors,
- restore from the database dump
- and run the command again.

Otherwise, there could be migrations that end up with errors,
but on the second run, they are not executed again, which could lead to the mess with the database schema, entity metadata, or entity config.

Also `oro:migration:load` command is not self-sufficient. There could be a need to warm up some entity configuration after the schema change. Please, try to run `oro:platform:update`, even if all the migrations are already executed, it would try to warm up all the caches and could fix an error.

Comment: Thanks! I came to that same conclusion the hard way :(